# Terminate shell pipe from interactive go cli

Tags: shell, go

I have a Go program that consumes "live" input from a shell pipe, eg:

```
tail -f some/file | my-program
```

`my-program` is an interactive program built with [`rivo/tview`](https://github.com/rivo/tview). I want to be able to close my program with Ctrl-C and have it also terminate the `tail -f` that supplies input to it.

Currently I have to hit Ctrl-C ***twice*** to get back to my shell prompt. Any way I can get back to my prompt by hitting Ctrl-C ***once***?

---

Adjusted my program per [@torek's explanation of progress groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65515934/32154) and [observation that I can get the progress group ID using `unix.Getpgid(pid)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65515667/terminate-shell-pipe-from-interactive-go-cli#comment115831987_65515934):

```golang
import (
  "os"
  "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

func main() {
  // do stuff with piped input

  pid := os.Getpid()
  pgid, err := unix.Getpgid(pid)

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("could not get process group id for pid: %v\n", pid)
  }

  processGroup, err := os.FindProcess(pgid)

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("could not find process for pid: %v\n", pgid)
  }

  processGroup.Signal(os.Interrupt)
}
```

This delivers my desired behavior from my original question.

I opted to not use `syscall` because of the [warning I found](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/):

> Deprecated: this package is locked down. Callers should use the corresponding package in the golang.org/x/sys repository instead. That is also where updates required by new systems or versions should be applied. See https://golang.org/s/go1.4-syscall for more information.

I plan to update my program to detect whether or not it was given a pipe using the [strategy outlined in this article](https://dev.to/napicella/linux-pipes-in-golang-2e8j), so when a pipe is detected, I'll do the above process group signaling on interrupt.

Any issues with that?

Comment: You can launch both the command from the my-program (in different mode). `cmd1 := exec.Command("tail", "-f", "somefile")` & `cmd2=exec.Command("my-program, "pipemode")`. Then using `io.Pipe()` pipe data from cmd1 to cmd2. This way you can control everything.  If this is suitable for your case?

Comment: @Abhijit-K Thanks for the suggestion, but this won't work in my use case. I want to use my program as a general-use utility to consume input from various difference places and as a result of various different commands, so putting those commands in code specializes my program too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll assume a Unix-like system, using a shell that understands and engages in *job control* (and they all do now).  When you run a command, the shell creates something called a *process group* or "pgroup" to hold each of the *processes* that make up the command.  If the command is a *pipeline* (as this one is), each process in the pipeline gets the same pgroup-ID (see [`setpgid`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setpgid.html)).

If the command is run in the *forgeground* (without `&`), the *controlling terminal* has this particular pgid assigned to it.  Pressing one of the signal-generating keys, such as <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL-\</kbd>, sends the corresponding signal (`SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` in these cases) to the pgroup, using an internal [`killpg`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/killpg.html) or equivalent.  This sends the signal to every member of the pgroup.

(Backgrounding a process is simply **cough** a matter of taking back the pgid on the controlling tty, then restarting the processes in the pipeline.  To make that happen is  not so simple, though, as indicated by the "restarting" here.)

The likely source of the problem here is that an *interactive program* will place the controlling terminal into *cbreak* or *raw* mode and disable some or all signalling from keyboard keys, so that, for instance, <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> no longer causes the *kernel's tty module* to send a signal at all.  Instead, if you see a key that should cause suspension (<kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd>) or termination, the program has to do its own suspending or terminating.  Programmers sometimes assume that this consists of simply suspending or terminating—but since the *entire pipeline* never got the signal in question, that's not the case, unless the entire shell pipeline consisted solely of the interactive program.

The fix is to have the program *send the signal* to its own pgroup, after doing any necessary cleanup (temporarily or permanently) of the controlling terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the writeup. You're correct in assuming a unix-like system. I see that there is [`os.Getgroups()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getgroups), which seems like it should return the PID for "its own pgroup," though I have no idea how to select the appropriate ID. Any suggestions?

Comment: `os.Getgroups()` returns group IDs rather than process/process-group IDs. `os` does not have a `Getpgid()` but I see there is one in `syscall` (eg https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/?GOOS=darwin#Getpgid - here's the problem with syscall, I get the one for my browser window) and also in `x/sys/unix`. I'm not sure which one to use when.

Comment: `syscall.Getpgid()` seems to return the correct PGID for me, comparing against the output of `ps o pid,command`. Adjusting my program to use this PGID does the exiting behavior I expect (see edit to my question). Do you know why you're getting the PGID for your browser "and also `x/sys/unix`"? I'm using Go v1.15.6 on macOS.

Comment: I just did a web browser (Google) search for "go getpgid". Since my browser is on Darwin (though my Go systems aren't), I get Darwin results. By clicking on more-targeted links, I get other results. Web sites are so helpful, aren't they? "Oh I see you're using Firefox on MacOS, I'll show you the MacOS answer, not the Linux answer you're actually looking for!"

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I misread what you typed earlier. I though you meant calling `syscall.Getpgid()` was giving you the PID for your web browser! My bad. ‍♂️